# Ubuntu 12.10 on Ati Radeon X1300/1550

Tags: drivers, ati

Will Ubuntu will work without any problem on ATI Radeon X1300/1550?

Are there drivers for it? Where do I get them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is only the FOSS drivers already installed. The closed source driver from AMD/ATI don't support anymore this card.